# Having trouble modding Minecraft old_alpha rd-132328

Tags: java, minecraft

So, I'm trying to mod one of the oldest versions of Minecraft. I've been doing pretty well so far, had no errors in the console, play test ran fine, texture/models looked fine and worked correctly. But when I try to put it into my Minecraft launcher, when I run it it won't work. I've renamed the .jar and .json files, referenced other versions to make sure the file layout for mine was correct, and did a run-through of the .json - twice, making sure I changed the ID.

**The log from the Game Output tab (If Launcher Log is needed, comment below. *UPDATED!* Thanks to @_ug !):**

```
/terrain.png -> 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: !!
at com.mojang.rubydung.Textures.loadTexture(Textures.java:63)
at com.mojang.rubydung.level.Chunk.rebuild(Chunk.java:48)
at com.mojang.rubydung.level.Chunk.render(Chunk.java:78)
at com.mojang.rubydung.level.LevelRenderer.render(LevelRenderer.java:53)
at com.mojang.rubydung.RubyDung.render(RubyDung.java:295)
at com.mojang.rubydung.RubyDung.run(RubyDung.java:122)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.mojang.rubydung.Textures.loadTexture(Textures.java:41)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Isaac_2\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\Minecraft rd-132328 Mod (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
... 8 more
```

That's pretty much all. I'll put the main code as well:

**RubyDung (Main) :**

```
package com.mojang.rubydung;

import com.mojang.rubydung.character.Creeper;
import com.mojang.rubydung.character.Cube;
import com.mojang.rubydung.character.Zombie;
import com.mojang.rubydung.character.Zombie2;
import com.mojang.rubydung.level.Chunk;
import com.mojang.rubydung.level.Level;
import com.mojang.rubydung.level.LevelRenderer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class RubyDung
  implements Runnable
{
  private static final boolean FULLSCREEN_MODE = false;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private FloatBuffer fogColor = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
  private Timer timer = new Timer(60.0F);
  private Level level;
  private LevelRenderer levelRenderer;
  private Player player;
  private ArrayList<Zombie> zombies = new ArrayList();
  private ArrayList<Zombie2> zombies2 = new ArrayList();
  private ArrayList<Creeper> creeper = new ArrayList();

  private IntBuffer viewportBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);

  private IntBuffer selectBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2000);
  private HitResult hitResult = null;

  public void init()
    throws LWJGLException, IOException
  {
    int col = 920330;
    float fr = 0.5F;
    float fg = 0.8F;
    float fb = 1.0F;
    this.fogColor.put(new float[] { (col >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255.0F, (col >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255.0F, (col & 0xFF) / 255.0F, 1.0F });
    this.fogColor.flip();

    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1024, 768));

    Display.create();
    Keyboard.create();
    Mouse.create();

    this.width = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    this.height = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

    GL11.glEnable(3553);
    GL11.glShadeModel(7425);
    GL11.glClearColor(fr, fg, fb, 0.0F);
    GL11.glClearDepth(1.0D);
    GL11.glEnable(2929);
    GL11.glDepthFunc(515);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(5889);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    GL11.glMatrixMode(5888);

    this.level = new Level(256, 256, 64);
    this.levelRenderer = new LevelRenderer(this.level);
    this.player = new Player(this.level);

    Mouse.setGrabbed(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
      this.zombies.add(new Zombie(this.level, 128.0F, 0.0F, 128.0F));
      this.zombies2.add(new Zombie2(this.level, 128.0F, 0.0F, 128.0F));
      this.creeper.add(new Creeper(this.level, 128.0F, 0.0F, 128.0F));
    }
  }

  public void destroy()
  {
    this.level.save();

    Mouse.destroy();
    Keyboard.destroy();
    Display.destroy();
  }

  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      init();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Failed to start RubyDung", 0);
      System.exit(0);
    }

    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    try
    {
      do
      {
        this.timer.advanceTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.timer.ticks; i++)
        {
          tick();
        }
        render(this.timer.a);
        frames++;

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastTime + 1000L)
        {
          System.out.println(frames + " fps, " + Chunk.updates);
          Chunk.updates = 0;

          lastTime += 1000L;
          frames = 0;
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(1)) break;  } while (!Display.isCloseRequested());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      destroy();
    }
  }

  public void tick()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.zombies.size(); i++)
    {
      ((Zombie)this.zombies.get(i)).tick();
      ((Zombie2)this.zombies2.get(i)).tick();
      ((Creeper)this.creeper.get(i)).tick();
    }

    this.player.tick();
  }

  private void moveCameraToPlayer(float a)
  {
    GL11.glTranslatef(0.0F, 0.0F, -0.3F);
    GL11.glRotatef(this.player.xRot, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    GL11.glRotatef(this.player.yRot, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);

    float x = this.player.xo + (this.player.x - this.player.xo) * a;
    float y = this.player.yo + (this.player.y - this.player.yo) * a;
    float z = this.player.zo + (this.player.z - this.player.zo) * a;
    GL11.glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
  }

  private void setupCamera(float a)
  {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(5889);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(70.0F, this.width / this.height, 0.05F, 1000.0F);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(5888);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    moveCameraToPlayer(a);
  }

  private void setupPickCamera(float a, int x, int y)
  {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(5889);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    this.viewportBuffer.clear();
    GL11.glGetInteger(2978, this.viewportBuffer);
    this.viewportBuffer.flip();
    this.viewportBuffer.limit(16);
    GLU.gluPickMatrix(x, y, 5.0F, 5.0F, this.viewportBuffer);
    GLU.gluPerspective(70.0F, this.width / this.height, 0.05F, 1000.0F);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(5888);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    moveCameraToPlayer(a);
  }

  private void pick(float a)
  {
    this.selectBuffer.clear();
    GL11.glSelectBuffer(this.selectBuffer);
    GL11.glRenderMode(7170);
    setupPickCamera(a, this.width / 2, this.height / 2);
    this.levelRenderer.pick(this.player);
    int hits = GL11.glRenderMode(7168);
    this.selectBuffer.flip();
    this.selectBuffer.limit(this.selectBuffer.capacity());

    long closest = 0L;
    int[] names = new int[10];
    int hitNameCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; i++)
    {
      int nameCount = this.selectBuffer.get();
      long minZ = this.selectBuffer.get();
      this.selectBuffer.get();

      long dist = minZ;

      if ((dist < closest) || (i == 0))
      {
        closest = dist;
        hitNameCount = nameCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < nameCount; j++)
          names[j] = this.selectBuffer.get();
      }
      else
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < nameCount; j++) {
          this.selectBuffer.get();
        }
      }
    }
    if (hitNameCount > 0)
    {
      this.hitResult = new HitResult(names[0], names[1], names[2], names[3], names[4]);
    }
    else
    {
      this.hitResult = null;
    }
  }

  public void render(float a)
  {
    float xo = Mouse.getDX();
    float yo = Mouse.getDY();
    this.player.turn(xo, yo);
    pick(a);

    while (Mouse.next())
    {
      if ((Mouse.getEventButton() == 1) && (Mouse.getEventButtonState()))
      {
        if (this.hitResult != null)
        {
          this.level.setTile(this.hitResult.x, this.hitResult.y, this.hitResult.z, 0);
        }
      }
      if ((Mouse.getEventButton() == 0) && (Mouse.getEventButtonState()))
      {
        if (this.hitResult != null)
        {
          int x = this.hitResult.x;
          int y = this.hitResult.y;
          int z = this.hitResult.z;

          if (this.hitResult.f == 0) y--;
          if (this.hitResult.f == 1) y++;
          if (this.hitResult.f == 2) z--;
          if (this.hitResult.f == 3) z++;
          if (this.hitResult.f == 4) x--;
          if (this.hitResult.f == 5) x++;

          this.level.setTile(x, y, z, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    while (Keyboard.next())
    {
      if ((Keyboard.getEventKey() == 28) && (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()))
      {
        this.level.save();
      }

    }

    GL11.glClear(16640);
    setupCamera(a);

    GL11.glEnable(2884);
    GL11.glEnable(2912);
    GL11.glFogi(2917, 2048);
    GL11.glFogf(2914, 0.2F);
    GL11.glFog(2918, this.fogColor);

    GL11.glDisable(2912);
    this.levelRenderer.render(this.player, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.zombies.size(); i++)
    {
      ((Zombie)this.zombies.get(i)).render(a);
      ((Zombie2)this.zombies2.get(i)).render(a);
      ((Creeper)this.creeper.get(i)).render(a);
    }
    GL11.glEnable(2912);
    this.levelRenderer.render(this.player, 1);
    GL11.glDisable(3553);

    if (this.hitResult != null)
    {
      this.levelRenderer.renderHit(this.hitResult);
    }

    new Cube(0, 0);
    GL11.glDisable(2912);

    Display.update();
  }

  public static void checkError()
  {
    int e = GL11.glGetError();
    if (e != 0)
    {
      throw new IllegalStateException(GLU.gluErrorString(e));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException
  {
    new Thread(new RubyDung()).start();
  }
}
```

**Textures (Texture Rendering) :**

```
package com.mojang.rubydung;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Textures
{
  private static HashMap<String, Integer> idMap = new HashMap();

  private static int lastId = -9999999;

  public static int loadTexture(String resourceName, int mode)
  {
    try
    {
      if (idMap.containsKey(resourceName))
      {
        return ((Integer)idMap.get(resourceName)).intValue();
      }

      IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
      ib.clear();
      GL11.glGenTextures(ib);
      int id = ib.get(0);
      idMap.put(resourceName, Integer.valueOf(id));
      System.out.println(resourceName + " -> " + id);

      GL11.glBindTexture(3553, id);

      GL11.glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, mode);
      GL11.glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, mode);

      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Textures.class.getResource(resourceName));
      int w = img.getWidth();
      int h = img.getHeight();

      ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(w * h * 4);
      int[] rawPixels = new int[w * h];
      img.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rawPixels, 0, w);
      for (int i = 0; i < rawPixels.length; i++)
      {
        int a = rawPixels[i] >> 24 & 0xFF;
        int r = rawPixels[i] >> 16 & 0xFF;
        int g = rawPixels[i] >> 8 & 0xFF;
        int b = rawPixels[i] & 0xFF;

        rawPixels[i] = (a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r);
      }
      pixels.asIntBuffer().put(rawPixels);
      GLU.gluBuild2DMipmaps(3553, 6408, w, h, 6408, 5121, pixels);

      return id;
    }
    catch (IOException localIOException) {
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("!!");
  }
}
```

**And Chunk (Block Rendering) :**

```
package com.mojang.rubydung.level;

import com.mojang.rubydung.Textures;
import com.mojang.rubydung.phys.AABB;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Chunk
{
  public AABB aabb;
  public final Level level;
  public final int x0;
  public final int y0;
  public final int z0;
  public final int x1;
  public final int y1;
  public final int z1;
  private boolean dirty = true;
  private int lists = -1;

  private static Tesselator t = new Tesselator();

  public static int rebuiltThisFrame = 0;
  public static int updates = 0;

  public Chunk(Level level, int x0, int y0, int z0, int x1, int y1, int z1)
  {
    this.level = level;
    this.x0 = x0;
    this.y0 = y0;
    this.z0 = z0;
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.z1 = z1;

    this.aabb = new AABB(x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1);
    this.lists = GL11.glGenLists(2);
  }

  private void rebuild(int layer)
  {
    if (rebuiltThisFrame == 2) return;
    this.dirty = false;

    updates += 1;

    rebuiltThisFrame += 1;

    int id = Textures.loadTexture("/terrain.png", 9728);

    GL11.glNewList(this.lists + layer, 4864);
    GL11.glEnable(3553);
    GL11.glBindTexture(3553, id);
    t.init();
    int tiles = 0;
    for (int x = this.x0; x < this.x1; x++)
      for (int y = this.y0; y < this.y1; y++)
        for (int z = this.z0; z < this.z1; z++)
        {
          if (this.level.isTile(x, y, z))
          {
            int tex = y == this.level.depth * 2 / 3 ? 0 : 1;
            tiles++;
            if (tex == 0)
              Tile.rock.render(t, this.level, layer, x, y, z);
            else
              Tile.grass.render(t, this.level, layer, x, y, z);
          }
        }
    t.flush();
    GL11.glDisable(3553);
    GL11.glEndList();
  }

  public void render(int layer)
  {
    if (this.dirty)
    {
      rebuild(0);
      rebuild(1);
    }

    GL11.glCallList(this.lists + layer);
  }

  public void setDirty()
  {
    this.dirty = true;
  }
}
```

**Also image of file tree:**

[image]

Thanks in advance guys! if you need any more information, just ask. I'll be following this post pretty frequently.

P.S: This is my first post, so forgive me if I made any errors or didn't make something clear! I'm very new to this, and only 13, so any positive criticism, ideas, tips, would all be greatly appreciated! Also, yes, I looked all over google to find the answer to my question, but didn't find anything even remotely close to what I was looking for, in fact, I don't think many people have trying to do what I am currently doing right now, especially not in only the second version of this game currently available. I chose ad-132328 because of its simplicity and basic layout of code, that way, because I'm fairly new to this, I could get a good idea of what I'm modifying, and have a basic template! :)

Comment: Its alot to ask for someone to dig through all your source on a different website. Its a whole new beast when your asking them to decompile your class files to view your source... If you want an answer your likely going to have to post some of your relevant code in your question. I know nothing of Minecrafts source but you might try loading the texture by `classpath:/terrain.png`

Comment: @ug_  I'm sorry, I wasn't able to post more than two links, and posting all of it raw, or even with the code tag, would've been too much on the post. I'll try what you suggested though! :)

Comment: @ug_ Made it a whole lot easier to help me, but sorry it wasn't like that in the first place. Also, I wasn't able to get the classpath thing to work, but thanks for the help anyway! ;)

Comment: you have your catch statment just toss the exception and instead throw a runtime exception with "!!". I would recommend agaisnt that as you then dont know why you had the error.

`catch (IOException localIOException) {} throw new RuntimeException("!!")`

Instead wrap the IOException in the runtime exception

`catch(IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException("INSERT MESSAGE HERE", e); }`

Comment: @ug_ It didn't work, but it helped out a lot! I got a new log and it seems to explain a lot more! I'll post above! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it our myself, but I feel really stupid because of how blatant the problem was. Of course, it was because I put spaces in the .jar, .json, and version folder... :P

Thanks @_ug for the help though in finding out what the problem was! (the extended log output was very helpful!)